# ios hook into incoming phone ring

Tags: ios, hook, cydia-substrate

I'm working on a mobile substrate tweak and trying to find out how to hook into the phone ringing method. I've been looking through [this](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework) framework, but haven't found anything promising yet. Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: What exactly are you want to achieve? "hook into the phone ringing method" - you want to find which method plays ringtone when there is an incoming phone call? If yes then you probably looking in the right place. That's where all phone call stuff is since iOS 7.

Comment: exactly. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ringtone is played using `SBUserAgent -(void)playRingtoneAtPath:(id) vibrationPattern:(id)`. There is also another method that may be worth hooking - `SBSoundController -(BOOL)_playRingtone:(id)`. It doesn't get called when there is an incoming call but still. May be Apple will use it in the future iOS versions.

Tested only on iOS 7. I checked older iOS headers. `playRingtoneAtPath` is there since iOS 5, `_playRingtone` - since iOS 6.